# javascript adding into arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to be able to add a student and a grade. however, I am having a difficult time figuring out how to enter a grade. This is what I have so far. When I run the program like this I get: `[ Student { name: 'Bob', grades: [], totalGrades: 0 } ]` Any help would be appreciated!

The commented out section was an attempt at adding grades, however, I did not work at all.

```
function Student(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.grades = [];

    this.totalGrades = function(){
        this.totalGrades = 0;
        this.grades.forEach(grade => {
            this.totalGrade += grade;
        })
    }
}  

function Students(){
    this.students = [];
   // this.grades = [];

   /* this.addGrade = function(grade){
        this.grades.push(grade);
    }*/


    this.addStudent = function(student){
        this.students.push(student);
    }

    this.calcTotalGrades = function(){
        this.students.forEach(student => {
            student.totalGrades();
        })
    }
}

let students = new Students();
students.addStudent(new Student('Bob'));

students.calcTotalGrades();
console.log(students.students);
```

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: You're not returning anything from your methods (such as `calcTotalGrades` or `totalGrades`. You're literally just forEaching over them with no effect...

Comment: I need to be able to enter grades into the array like I have done with the names of the student

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have an `addGrades` to a `Students` because you're supposed to add grades to an individual student not all the students...

Comment: You wanna know how to add grades to a specific student?

Comment: Yes @MatheusReis

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, as a method of your `Students`:

```
this.addGrade = function(student,grade) {
    this.students.forEach(student => {
       if(student.name === student)
           student.grades.push(grade)
    }
}
```

To add a new grade:

```
students.addGrade('Bob',10);
```

Comment: How would I write the console.log? sorry for all of the silly questions, I'm quite new at this.

Comment: Check `grade` value in `student.grades` array before inserting to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Alexander, a student can have two or more equal grades, so, I'm not shure if this checking is necessary

Comment: @Spore2440, what do you want to show with the `console.log()`?

Comment: @Spore2440 Why don't you read some Javascript tutorial? | If you have another question, ask another question. Your original question has nothing to do with console.log.

Comment: Oh sorry, not the console.log I mean the how would I write the input for this. For the student name, I wrote: let students = new Students();
students.addStudent(new Student('Bob')); How would I go about getting a grade in there?

Comment: So there will be 2 grades with the same value. That isn't possible?

Comment: @Spore2440 , check the answer again

Comment: No there will not be 2 grades with the same value

Comment: Thank you very much MatheusReis, I appreciate you putting up with my silly questions!

Comment: Why not, @Alexander? The `grade` is just a value inside an `array`. An `array` can contain two(or more) equal values in different indexes.